# Google Mailer Class

Tags: c#

I have a mailer for Google as shown below, how can i adapt this for other mail systems?  Is there a better way of doing this? also how can i change the name of where the mail is from(the sender).
All help would be much appreciated, and thank you in advance

```
 MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
        message.From = new MailAddress(MailAddresds);
        message.Subject = messagesubject;
        message.Body = messagebody;


        message.To.Add(messageto);
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();

        client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, password);
        client.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        client.Port = 587;
        client.EnableSsl = true;
        client.Send(message);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just example:

```
public class MailMessage
{
   public string From{get;set;}
   public string To{get;set;}
   public string Body{get;set;}
   public string Subject{get;set;}
   ....
   //other common properties you may need
}


//interface 
public interface IMailService
{
    Send(MailMessage m);
}
```

concrete implementations:

```
public class GoogleMail : IMailService
{
    public Send(Message msg)
    { 
       //google mail specific code
    }
}


public class YahooMail : IMailService
{
    public Send(Message msg)
    { 
       //yahoo mail specific code
    }
}

.... Hotmail,...
```

somewhere in the code create a collection of supported mail services

```
var mailservices = new List<IMailService>();
mailservices.Add(new GoogleMail ());
mailservice.Add(new YahooMail ());
```

after, during the program run, pick the appropriate service to proceed user request.

Comment: might be something to do with the changing "MailMessage" and "Message" classes???

Comment: that is not a reason to downvotte (especially without any explanation)

Comment: I know, just offering a suggestion :)

Answer (score 1):

simple example:

```
using System.Web.Mail;

MailMessage objMessage = new MailMessage();
objMessage.From = "from";
objMessage.To = "to";
objMessage.Subject = "subject";
objMessage.BodyFormat = MailFormat.Text;
objMessage.Body = "body";
SmtpMail.SmtpServer = "SmtpServer";
SmtpMail.Send(objMessage);
```